# Oppo Neo 5 (2015) Stuck at Logo Screen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, boot-loop

So I rooted my phone successfully. Then after that, I installed Flashify to Flash CWM Based Recovery and shows "copying file to ....". After that it reboots to recovery and now it is just showing me the Oppo logo screen. I can't access the recovery even I press the key combination. Yes it shows ">>> Recovery Mode" but it is just stuck on the logo. Please anyone help !?


Here are some Info

- Android 5.0.1
- I have the stock ROM for my device

I also have a problem when I charge my phone, it automatically goes to recovery but still stuck at the logo screen

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you flashed a recovery that didn't support your device. Good news is since your rooted, you can unbrick your phone by obtaining your original rom.

If you didn't back up your rom/recovery, then you will need to download your STOCK rom off the internet and flash it via Odin.

Odin is a popular flashing tool for windows and mac. It works better on Windows.

ALSO, when flashing with odin, you will need a pit file. Pit file tells Odin where to correctly install the rom.

If your not familiar with flashing using odin, I recommend you look it up.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It says ODIN is for Samsung, Can I use it with my Oppo ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. But according to one site, if you install Oppo USB drivers, it SHOULD work. Just try it.

Comment: If you find difficulty with Odin, you can do the same with SP Flash tools too...
Hope this helps.

Comment: -1 Because Odin does not work with Oppo devices, and Oppo devices doesn't even have a Download/Fastboot mode, and who knows what will happen when the SoC signals Odin sends get mixed up with Oppo modified Mediatek SoC protocols...